# Dism and removing a "package" from an Installed windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, packages

I am exploring the possibility of removing "packages" from an Installed Windows 7 64bit. It is difficult to test deployment things when items were never installed to being with.

**My understanding so far:** Microsoft claims that these "packages" are hanging out in  bundles of seperated and distinct items for proper compatability, and interoperation of mixed .dll installations. They also claim that the system of belotion allows for an update to a program or system to be removed, reverting the program or system back to the way it was. They also state that only removal of a program will completly remove all the parts and pieces strewn through the system.  Ok got that.

**Goal:** To remove only ONE package, little baby steps, but I could not even accomplish the most simple and observable item.  Unfortunatly a search reveals millions of Vista based information resources and few Windows 7 specific, 64bit in my case.

Method #1 , I start as simple as I can

```
>DISM.exe > C:\packages.txt /online /get-packages
```

This give me a tiny list of packages (compared to a sysprep list)
Below is the only victom of this question, as seen in the packages list.

```
Package Identity : Microsoft-Windows-LocalPack-AU-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514
State : Installed
Release Type : Local Pack
Install Time : 9/21/2011 4:01 AM
```

The DISM log for that item

```
2011-10-13 08:34:31, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3700 Package Microsoft-Windows-LocalPack-AU-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514 with CBS state 7(CbsInstallStateInstalled) being mapped to dism state 5(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED) - CDISMPackage::LogInstallStateMapping
```

This is my failed attempt at uninstalling that package

```
C:\>dism.exe /image:c:\s2 /remove-package /packagename:Microsoft-Windows-LocalPa
ck-AU-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514
```

This is the error shown (in my world this error says "you have no idea how many steps this is going to take":-)

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Error: 2

Unable to access the image.
Make sure that the image path and the Windows directory for the image exist and
you have Read permissions on the folder.
```

Nowhere in the question , is it asked "Should I be doing this" or "Is this a bad idea" please limit negating comments to the goal of using MS packaging system, some way, or some better way. There is no doubt that I have no idea what I am doing, I am new to this method.

Disclaimer, Every removal of items from the OS has some ramifications, I have a backup ,and I am not afraid to use it. The purpose is for testing only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `dism` with a running operating system, you need to specify the `/online` flag.

Try this:

```
dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Microsoft-Windows-LocalPack-AU-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514
```