# I setup in control panel for 2 IME, but get 3, how can I remove the 3rd?

Tags: windows-7, ime

As image below, I only setup in Control Panel to get 2 IME (EN & JP) but got 3 (EN, JP, VI), how can I get rid of the VI IME ?

[image: error]

Comment: If you go to Add, instead of just being add, it looks like there are checkboxes, so even if your not adding it could be a place to look?  as seen in the The fifth picture  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12578/add-keyboard-languages-to-xp-vista-and-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesnot solve my problem :(

Comment: Ok, then the next method could be to use MSes packaging and install system, using DISM. I played with it a bit, and it had some language type stuff?  It wouldnt hurt to look. 'DISM.exe > C:\packages.txt /online /get-packages"  Then find this text file and gleen through it.  That command shows the installed packages. http://superuser.com/questions/346395/dism-and-removing-a-package-from-an-installed-windows-7-64bit  It is not quite clear here if Just part of something is installed?